# Diamond inheritance - call all parent functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

Say I've got the following (pseudo-)code:

```
class base{
public:
    virtual void callMe() = 0;
    virtual void doRender() = 0;
}

class a : public base{
public:
    virtual void callMe(){/*doA*/} override;
}

class b : public base{
public:
    virtual void callMe(){/*doB*/} override;
}

class myClass : public base, public a, public b{
public:
    virtual void doRender(){
        this->a::callMe();
        this->b::callMe();
    } override;
}
```

Would there be a way to write this differently? Something like:

```
class myClass : public base, public a, public b{
public:
    virtual void doRender(){
        this->allSupers::callMe();
    } override;
}
```

My goal with this would be to have a base class that can be extended to have different "features", all of which have to be executed on doRender.

I know I could of course keep track of these functions by means of a function pointer list in base, in which the subclasses put their own functions when constructed, but I'd like to avoid that. Having to iterate over these functions still gives me at least three lines of code in my final doRender. (Or one long unreadable line.)

I'm open for suggestions using templates.

Comment: To call a function of a base-class use ```a:::doRender()```. Inheriting from multiple classes with the same base class seems dangerous, is there a practical use case?

Comment: @Freakyy yes, there is a practical use case. I've got 4 "objects" which all need to execute different features when rendering, and most features do exist in two or three objects. I know how to call the base function, I'm doing so in my example, just that I'm used to using this-> to distinguish between local and static functions. Multiple class inheritance is not dangerous in C++ if you know what you're doing. There's a lot of good reading on the diamond problem, which is exactly this.

Comment: "I could of course keep track of these functions by means of a function pointer list in base": In that case, you are definitely missing on `virtual` inheritance. As your code stands, you don't have a single base `base`, but three: One is a direct base to `myClass`, and the other two bases `a` and `b` each have their own instance of `base` as their bases. All three are distinct from each other. If you want only one, as the quote implies, you must use the `virtual` keyword whenever you declare `base` as a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you actual problem at hand, you might be able to use the mixin-style.  Essentially you can have each class call the next `callMe` at the end (or begining) of their own `callMe`. One benefit is that `callMe` does not need to be a virtual function. Here is a minimal example ([online](http://cpp.sh/57rvc5)):

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
public:
    void callMe() {}; // Empty base case
    virtual void doRender() = 0;
};

template <class super>
class a : public super
{
public:
    void callMe()
    {
        std::cout << "doA" << '\n';

        super::callMe(); // Call the next
    };
};

template <class super>
class b : public super
{
public:
    void callMe()
    {
        std::cout << "doB" << '\n';

        super::callMe(); // Call the next
    };
};

template <class super>
class myClass_t : public super
{
public:
    void doRender()
    {
        super::callMe();
    };
};

using myClass = myClass_t<a<b<base> > >; // Defining the order of evaluation;

int main()
{
  myClass m;
  m.doRender();
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. I do wonder if there's a way to do this without having to do a call at the bottom of callMe, but have an upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

With variadic template, you may do:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class myClassTs : public base, public Ts...
{
public:
    virtual void doRender(){
        int dummy[] = {0, (Ts::callMe(), void(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Silent warning for unused variable
    } override;
}

using myClass = myClassTs<a, b>;
```

And in C++17, it would be

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class myClassTs : public base, public Ts...
{
public:
    virtual void doRender(){
        (static_cast<void>(Ts::callMe()), ...);
    } override;
}
```

Comment: Nice. How is the order of evaluation defined for this construct?

Comment: @Jonas: It is specified ;-) and it is from left to right, so for `class myClassTs<T1, T2>`, it would be `T1::callMe();T2::callMe();`.

Comment: Am I right to state that this should even work if it's in the base class? And could you maybe explain what the ` 0, ` and the `void(), 0)` are for? I'm assuming the `0,` is to make it work without any template parameters, but I'm at a complete loss about the `void(), 0)`.

Comment: The `void` is to prevent against evil overload operator comma.